# BottomNavigationView's menu not selected after navigating to other fragment, switching to other menu, and switching back to initial menu

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-navigation, android-bottomnav

I'm building an android application with 3 menus using bottom navigation. I created new project in Android Studio using Bottom Navigation Activity.

I renamed the fragment to:

- `InfoFragment.kt`
- `DetectFragment.kt`
- `AboutFragment.kt`

Renamed the layout in `src/main/res/layout` to:

- `fragment_info.xml`
- `fragment_detect.xml`
- `fragment_about.xml`

Renamed the menu in `src/main/res/menu` to:

- `navigation_info`
- `navigation_detect`
- `navigation_about`

In the `fragment_about.xml` I added a Button `buttonGoToFAQ` to navigate to `fragment_faq`  [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CW7WG.png) with this code in `AboutFragment.kt`

```kotlin
buttonGoToFAQ.setOnClickListener {
        val action = AboutFragmentDirections.actionFAQ()
        Navigation.findNavController(it).navigate(action)
    }
```

After I clicked BottomNavigationView menu either `navigation_info` or `navigation_detect`, and go back by clicking `navigation_about` menu, the selected menu on the BottomNavigationView is not changed.
[See this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8OVp.jpg).

What I want is the **menu `navigation_about` should have been selected instead of other menu**.

I already tried overriding `fun onStart()` and `fun onResume()` in `FAQFragment.kt` but to no avail.
`nav_view` is my BottomNavigationView.

```kotlin
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()

    (requireActivity().findViewById<View>(R.id.nav_view) as BottomNavigationView).selectedItemId =
        R.id.navigation_about
}
```

I also recognize that all the BottomNavigationView menu's id have the same ids as the id in the `src/main/res/navigation` xml file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some days, I finally get the answer by myself. First, I need to get the `BottomNavigationView` from `MainActivity`, after that, you can just change the menu item value from another fragment.

In `MainActivity.kt`:

```
companion object {
    lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
{
```

On Fragment,
Define `BottomNavigationView` and set the desired index in `onResume()`:

```
class FAQFragment : Fragment() {
    private val navView: BottomNavigationView = MainActivity.binding.navView

    ...

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()

        navView.menu.getItem(2).isChecked = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

This is the intended behavior, according to this link to Google's Issue tracker - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/210687967?pli=1

In a nutshell, Google wants us to use Nested Navigation Graphs to link `FaqFragment` and `AboutFragment`.
This will result in menu `navigation_about` to be selected whenever either of the fragments are opened.

1. In your `nav_graph.xml`, add a nested graph -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/infoFragment">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/infoFragment"
    android:name="......"
    android:label="..." >
        ....
</fragment>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/detectFragment"
    android:name="......"
    android:label="...." >
        ....
</fragment>  

<navigation android:id="@+id/toAboutNav"
    app:startDestination="@id/aboutFragment">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/aboutFragment"
        android:name="....."
        android:label="....." >
        .......
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/faqFragment"
        android:name="...."
        android:label="...">
        ....
    </fragment>
</navigation>
</navigation>
```

2. Also, in your menu folder, make the following change in your `bottom_nav_menu.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@id/infoFragment"
        android:icon="...."
        android:title="...." />
    <item
        android:id="@id/detectFragment"
        android:icon="...."
        android:title="...." />
    <item
        android:id="@id/toAboutNav"
        android:icon="...."
        android:title="...." />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can navigate manually and always return `true` to the `OnItemSelectedListener` to achieve menu item selection.

```
binding.bottomNavigation.setOnItemSelectedListener { item ->
    NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(item, navController)
    true
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As also suggested by @Francis, this is what you're looking for. I saw your answer but that is not the optimal solution, that is just a workaround that you have found.

```js
bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener {
  item - >
    // In order to get the expected behavior, you have to call default Navigation method manually
    NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(item, navController)

  return @setOnItemSelectedListener true
}
```